# TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Tags: mongoose, model

```
const {mongoose, Schema} = require('mongoose')

const mySchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    message:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: new Date
    } 
})



module.exports = mongoose.model('message', mySchema)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas incluyendo al modulo mongoose de una manera errónea.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const mySchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    message:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: new Date
    } 
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('message', mySchema)
```

El problema radica en que hay un inconveniente al aplicar la desestructuración al modulo de mongoose.
[Para mas información acerca de este problema.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7009)

Suerte.